# Why file handler can not be used more than once in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am new to python, learning data structures now. and i got stuck with files. I  felt this very unusual, can anyone help me with a good reason why this is happening. here is my code.

(this is the link for text file http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt)

```
fh = open('romeo.txt')

for line in fh:
    print line
```

**Output:**

> ï»¿But soft what light through yonder window breaks
>   It is the east and Juliet is the sun
>   Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
>   Who is already sick and pale with grief

```
for line in fh:
    print line
```

Here I am not able to print the lines using `fh` for the second time, it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because iterating through the lines moves the current position.

One of the things you could do is move the position back to the start:

```
fh.seek(0)
```

You may also find this Python file reading tutorial useful: http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html